# Accessing an earlier release?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, flash-builder

Sorry if this has been asked before but I couldn't find a clear answer.

I am using the Eclipse-based Flash Builder with Github. I need to access and revise an earlier version of an app I am currently working on. I don't want to rebase my local version and lose what I have. I also don't think I want to push the  current buggy version I have up to Github.

Could someone outline how to do this? (get version "B" from Github while retaining the current version "E" I am working on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are working on `E`, so this is a local branch. Make sure you commit your current work to `E` so you have a clean working directory.
- Now switch to branch `B` (`git checkout B`) Maybe you have to set up a local branch that tracks branch `B` on github (`git checkout -t origin/B` creates a local branch that tracks the origin-branch and switches to it).

this doesn't affect your local branch `E`. You can just switch back to it when you're finished with the work on `B` (`git checkout E` will switch back to this branch).

`rebase` does something completely different: you would use it if you have a feature or a change in general on one branch that you want to bring to another branch